# Android animation for long click

Tags: android, android-animation

I need to create a kind of animation for my Android `button` when user **hold and press** (long click). see following example:

[image]

Any idea how to implement with Android Studio (for Android 7 and above)?

Comment: What all have you tried till yet to achieve this ?